# How to handle intersections in an algorithm trying to draw ascii diagrams?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, cursor-movement, replace

For learning purpose, I'm trying to reimplement a small subset of the features provided by the [DrawIt](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=40) plugin.

So far, here's what I have:

```
" data "{{{

let s:draw_state = 'disabled'

let s:draw_chars = {
                   \ 'minus'     : '-',
                   \ 'pipe'      : '|',
                   \ 'plus'      : '+',
                   \ 'backslash' : '\',
                   \ 'slash'     : '/',
                   \ 'X'         : 'X',
                   \ }

"}}}
" mappings "{{{

nno <silent> m_        :<C-U>call <SID>draw_change_state(0)<CR>
nno <silent> m<space>  :<C-U>call <SID>draw_change_state(1)<CR>
nno <silent> m<Bar>    :<C-U>call <SID>draw_stop()<CR>

"}}}
" beyond_last_line"{{{

fu! s:draw_beyond_last_line(key) abort
    return (a:key ==? '<Down>' || a:key ==? '<PageDown>' || a:key ==? '<End>' || a:key ==# 'v' )
            \ && s:draw_state ==# 'drawing' && line('.') == line('$')
endfu

"}}}
" change_state "{{{

fu! s:draw_change_state(erasing_mode) abort

    if s:draw_state ==# 'disabled'
        let s:ve_save = &ve
        let s:draw_original_mappings = s:save_mappings([
                                                       \ '<Left>',
                                                       \ '<Right>',
                                                       \ '<Down>',
                                                       \ '<Up>',
                                                       \ '<S-Left>',
                                                       \ '<S-Right>',
                                                       \ '<S-Down>',
                                                       \ '<S-Up>',
                                                       \ '<',
                                                       \ '>',
                                                       \ 'v',
                                                       \ '^',
                                                       \ ],
                                                       \
                                                       \   'n',
                                                       \       1)

        " The last argument passed to `s:save_mappings()` is 1. "{{{
        " This is very important. It means that we save global mappings.
        " We aren't interested in buffer-local ones.
        " Why?
        " It would be difficult to restore them, we would need to first restore
        " the focus to the buffer where they were initially saved.
        " And they could only be used in the current buffer, not in others.
        "
        " I prefer to not bother.
        " If the user mapped the keys locally, our global mapping will work
        " everywhere except in the current buffer and buffers where they
        " installed similar buffer-local mappings.
        "
        " Trying to support this case would create too much complexity.
        " We would need to override the buffer-local mappings from the user in
        " every buffer where they exist. It would probably require an autocmd,
        " watching some event, like `BufEnter,BufNewFile`.
        " It would have to check whether the user did install a buffer-local
        " mapping using the keys we're interested in, and in that case,
        " save the info about the mapping as well as the position of the buffer
        " in the buffer list.
        "
        " Once the user stops drawing, we would then need to parse all this
        " info, to give the focus to various buffers and restore the mappings
        " in them.
        " Then, we would need to restore the layout… FUBAR
        "
        " }}}

    endif

    let s:draw_state = {
                       \ 'disabled' : a:erasing_mode ? 'erasing'  : 'drawing' ,
                       \ 'drawing'  : a:erasing_mode ? 'erasing'  : 'disabled',
                       \ 'erasing'  : a:erasing_mode ? 'disabled' : 'drawing' ,
                       \ }[s:draw_state]

    call s:draw_update_mappings()
endfu

"}}}
" install_mappings "{{{

fu! s:draw_install_mappings() abort
    let args = ' <nowait> <silent> '

    for l:key in ['Left>', 'Right>', 'Down>', 'Up>', 'PageDown>', 'PageUp>', 'Home>', 'End>']
        exe 'nno '.args.' <'.l:key.' :<C-U>call <SID>draw_it('.string('<lt>'.l:key).')<CR>'
    endfor

    for l:key in ['S-Left>', 'S-Right>', 'S-Down>', 'S-Up>']
        exe 'nno '.args.' <'.l:key.' :<C-U>call <SID>draw_shift_arrow_motion("<lt>'.l:key.'")<CR>'
    endfor

    for l:key in ['<', '>', 'v', '^']
        exe 'nno '.args.l:key.' :<C-U>call <SID>draw_it('.string(l:key).')<CR>'
    endfor
endfu

"}}}
" intersection "{{{

fu! s:draw_intersection(key) abort
    if count(['<Left>', '<Right>', '<Down>', '<Up>'], a:key)
        return '+'

    elseif count(['<End>', '<Home>', '<PageDown>', '<PageUp>'], a:key)
        return 'X'
    endif
endfu

"}}}
" is_changing_dir "{{{

fu! s:draw_is_changing_dir(key) abort
    return getline('.')[col('.')-1] ==# s:draw_chars[s:draw_opposite(a:key)]
endfu

"}}}
" it "{{{

fu! s:draw_it(key) abort

    if s:draw_beyond_last_line(a:key)
        call append('.', '')
    endif

    if count([
             \ '<Left>',
             \ '<Right>',
             \ '<Down>',
             \ '<Up>',
             \ '<PageDown>',
             \ '<PageUp>',
             \ '<End>',
             \ '<Home>'
             \ ],
             \     a:key)

        let keys = (
                 \   s:draw_is_changing_dir(a:key)
                 \     ? s:draw_replace_char(s:draw_intersection(a:key))
                 \     : ''
                 \ )
                 \ .s:draw_motion(a:key)
                 \ .s:draw_replace_char(a:key)

    elseif count(['^', 'v', '<', '>'], a:key)

        let keys = 'r'.a:key.s:draw_motion(a:key).'r'.a:key

    endif

    call feedkeys(keys, 'in')
endfu

"}}}
" key2name "{{{

fu! s:draw_key2name(key) abort
    if a:key ==? '<Left>' || a:key ==? '<Right>'
        return 'minus'

    elseif a:key ==? '<Down>' || a:key ==? '<Up>'
        return 'pipe'

    elseif a:key ==? '<End>' || a:key ==? '<PageUp>'
        return 'slash'

    elseif a:key ==? '<Home>' || a:key ==? '<PageDown>'
        return 'backslash'

    elseif a:key ==? '+'
        return 'plus'

    elseif a:key ==# 'X'
        return 'X'

    endif
endfu

"}}}
" motion "{{{

fu! s:draw_motion(key) abort
    if a:key ==? '<Left>'
        return "\<Left>"

    elseif a:key ==? '<Right>'
        return "\<Right>"

    elseif a:key ==? '<Down>'
        return "\<Down>"

    elseif a:key ==? '<Up>'
        return "\<Up>"

    elseif a:key ==? '<PageDown>'
        return "\<Right>\<Down>"

    elseif a:key ==? '<PageUp>'
        return "\<Right>\<Up>"

    elseif a:key ==? '<Home>'
        return "\<Left>\<Up>"

    elseif a:key ==? '<End>'
        return "\<Left>\<Down>"

    elseif a:key ==# 'v'
        return "\<Down>"

    elseif a:key ==# '^'
        return "\<Up>"

    elseif a:key ==# '<'
        return "\<Left>"

    elseif a:key ==# '>'
        return "\<Right>"

    endif
endfu

"}}}
" opposite "{{{

fu! s:draw_opposite(key) abort
    if a:key ==? '<Down>' || a:key ==? '<Up>'
        return 'minus'

    elseif a:key ==? '<Left>' || a:key ==? '<Right>'
        return 'pipe'

    elseif a:key ==? '<Home>' || a:key ==? '<PageDown>'
        return 'slash'

    elseif a:key ==? '<End>' || a:key ==? '<PageUp>'
        return 'backslash'
    endif
endfu

"}}}
" remove_mappings "{{{

fu! s:draw_remove_mappings() abort
    for l:key in [
                 \ '<Left>',
                 \ '<Right>',
                 \ '<Down>',
                 \ '<Up>',
                 \ '<S-Left>',
                 \ '<S-Right>',
                 \ '<S-Down>',
                 \ '<S-Up>',
                 \ '<PageDown>',
                 \ '<PageUp>',
                 \ '^',
                 \ 'v',
                 \ '<',
                 \ '>',
                 \ ]

        " Why unmap silently?
        "
        " Because we could be dumb and ask to disable the drawing mode manually
        " (`m|`), even though it's already disabled.
        " It could raise errors, if the keys are already unmapped (the user didn't
        " map them to anything by default).

        sil! exe 'nunmap '.l:key
    endfor

        call s:restore_mappings(s:draw_original_mappings)
endfu

"}}}
" replace_char"{{{

fu! s:draw_replace_char(key) abort
    " This function is called before and then after a motion (left, up, …).
    " It must return the character to draw.
    "
    " When it's called AFTER a motion, and we're erasing, the character HAS TO
    " be a space.
    " When it's called BEFORE a motion, and we're erasing, we COULD (should?)
    " return nothing.
    "
    " Nevertheless, we let the function return a space.
    " It doesn't seem to cause an issue.
    " This way, we don't have to pass a 2nd argument to know when it's called
    " (before or after a motion).

    return 'r'
         \ .(
         \   s:draw_state ==# 'erasing'
         \   ? ' '
         \   : s:draw_chars[s:draw_key2name(a:key)]
         \  )
endfu

"}}}
" restore_mappings "{{{

" Warning:
" Don't try to restore a buffer local mapping unless you're sure that, when
" `s:restore_mappings()` is called, you're in the same buffer where
" `s:save_mappings()` was originally called.
"
" If you aren't in the same buffer, you could install a buffer-local mapping
" inside a buffer where this mapping didn't exist before.
" It could cause unexpected behavior on the user's system.
"
" Usage:
" call s:restore_mappings(my_saved_mappings)
"
" `my_saved_mappings` is a dictionary obtained earlier by calling
" `s:save_mappings()`.
" Its keys are the keys used in the mappings.
" Its values are the info about those mappings stored in sub-dictionaries.
"
" There's nothing special to pass to `s:restore_mappings()`, no other
" argument, no wrapping inside a 3rd dictionary, or anything. Just this dictionary.

fu! s:restore_mappings(mappings) abort

    for mapping in values(a:mappings)
        if !empty(mapping)
            exe    (mapping.noremap ? ' nnoremap ' : ' nmap ')
               \ . (mapping.buffer  ? ' <buffer> ' : '')
               \ . (mapping.expr    ? ' <expr>   ' : '')
               \ . (mapping.nowait  ? ' <nowait> ' : '')
               \ . (mapping.silent  ? ' <silent> ' : '')
               \ .  mapping.lhs
               \ . ' '
               \ . substitute(mapping.rhs, '<SID>', '<SNR>'.mapping.sid.'_', 'g')
        endif
    endfor

endfu

"}}}
" save_mappings "{{{

" Usage:
"
"     let my_global_mappings = s:save_mappings(['key1', 'key2', …], 'n', 1)
"     let my_local_mappings  = s:save_mappings(['key1', 'key2', …], 'n', 0)
"

" Output example: "{{{
"
"     { '<left>' :
"                \
"                \ {'silent': 0,
"                \ 'noremap': 1,
"                \ 'lhs': '<Left>',
"                \ 'mode': 'n',
"                \ 'nowait': 0,
"                \ 'expr': 0,
"                \ 'sid': 7,
"                \ 'rhs': ':echo ''foo''<CR>',
"                \ 'buffer': 1},
"                \
"     \ '<right>':
"                \
"                \ { 'silent': 0,
"                \ 'noremap': 1,
"                \ 'lhs': '<Right>',
"                \ 'mode': 'n',
"                \ 'nowait': 0,
"                \ 'expr': 0,
"                \ 'sid': 7,
"                \ 'rhs': ':echo ''bar''<CR>',
"                \ 'buffer': 1,
"                \ },
"                \}
"
" }}}

fu! s:save_mappings(keys, mode, global) abort
    let mappings = {}

    " If a key is used in a global mapping and a local one, by default,
    " `maparg()` only returns information about the local one.
    " We want to be able to get info about a global mapping even if a local
    " one shadows it.
    " To do that, we will temporarily unmap the local mapping.

    if a:global
        for l:key in a:keys
            let buf_local_map = maparg(l:key, a:mode, 0, 1)

            " temporarily unmap the local mapping
            sil! exe a:mode.'unmap <buffer> '.l:key

            " save info about the global one
            let mappings[l:key] = maparg(l:key, a:mode, 0, 1)

            " restore the local one
            call s:restore_mappings({l:key : buf_local_map})
        endfor

    " TRY to return info local mappings.
    " If they exist it will work, otherwise it will return info about global
    " mappings.
    else
        for l:key in a:keys
            let mappings[l:key] = maparg(l:key, a:mode, 0, 1)
        endfor
    endif

    return mappings
endfu


"}}}
" shift_arrow_motion "{{{

fu! s:draw_shift_arrow_motion(key) abort
    if a:key ==? '<S-Down>' && line('.') == line('$')
        call append('.', '')
    endif
    call feedkeys(eval('"'.'\'.substitute(a:key, '\cs-', '', '').'"'), 'in')
endfu

"}}}
" stop "{{{

fu! s:draw_stop() abort
    let s:draw_state = 'disabled'
    call s:draw_remove_mappings()
    let &ve = s:ve_save
    echom '[Drawing/Erasing] disabled'
endfu

"}}}
" update_mappings"{{{

fu! s:draw_update_mappings() abort
    if s:draw_state ==# 'disabled'
        call s:draw_stop()

    else
        call s:draw_install_mappings()
        set ve=all
        echom '['.substitute(s:draw_state, '.', '\u&', '').'] '.'enabled'

    endif
endfu

"}}}
```

Here are the mappings I'm currently using:

```
m_            start/toggle drawing
m<space>      start/toggle erasing
m|            stop everything

<left>        insert `-` and move left
<right>       insert `-` and move right
<down>        insert `|` and move down
<up>          insert `|` and move up

<s-left>      move left
<s-right>     move right
<s-down>      move down
<s-up>        move up

<Home>        insert `\` and move up
<PageUp>      insert `/` and move up
<End>         insert `/` and move down
<PageDown>    insert `\` and move down
v             insert `v` and move down
^             insert `^` and move up
<             insert `<` and move left
>             insert `>` and move right
```

---

But I don't know how to handle intersections. What I would like to achieve is the following:

1. If the character I'm inserting is not parallel to the one where I was just before, replace the latter with an intersection. For example, if I'm on a `-` and I hit `<Up>` or `<Down>`, it should insert a `|` which is not parallel to `-`. So, `-` should be replaced with `+`.
2. If the character I'm inserting is replacing an existing character which is not parallel, do the same thing. For example, if I hit `<PageDown>` to move down and insert a `\`, but the character on which I land after the `Down` motion is a `/`, then instead of inserting `\` like it's supposed to, insert a `X` instead.

---

I think the current code handles the first condition, but not the second one.

For example:[image]

The corners of the drawings on the left are correctly drawn using the `+` and `X` characters, but the ones on the right don't handle the intersection at all.

Here's what the upper drawing on the right does:

```
             |              
       |     |              
       |     |       |      
       |     |       |      
       |     |       |      
-------|-----|-------|------
       |     |       |      
       |     |       |      
       |             |
```

Here's what I want:

```
             |              
       |     |              
       |     |       |      
       |     |       |      
       |     |       |      
-------+-----+-------+------
       |     |       |      
       |     |       |      
       |             |
```

Here's what the lower drawing on the right does:

```
\           
 \          
  \         
   \      / 
    \    / /
     \  /// 
      \///  
      ///   
     ///\   
    ///  \  
    //    \ 
           \
```

Here's what I want:

```
\           
 \          
  \         
   \      / 
    \    / /
     \  /// 
      \///  
      /X/   
     ///\   
    ///  \  
    //    \ 
           \
```

---

The problem comes from this function:

```
fu! s:draw_it(key) abort

    if s:draw_beyond_last_line(a:key)
        call append('.', '')
    endif

    if count([
             \ '<Left>',
             \ '<Right>',
             \ '<Down>',
             \ '<Up>',
             \ '<PageDown>',
             \ '<PageUp>',
             \ '<End>',
             \ '<Home>'
             \ ],
             \     a:key)

        let keys = (
                 \   s:draw_is_changing_dir(a:key)
                 \     ? s:draw_replace_char(s:draw_intersection(a:key))
                 \     : ''
                 \ )
                 \ .s:draw_motion(a:key)
                 \ .s:draw_replace_char(a:key)

    elseif count(['^', 'v', '<', '>'], a:key)

        let keys = 'r'.a:key.s:draw_motion(a:key).'r'.a:key

    endif

    call feedkeys(keys, 'in')
endfu
```

And more specifically from this part:

```
    let keys = (
             \   s:draw_is_changing_dir(a:key)
             \     ? s:draw_replace_char(s:draw_intersection(a:key))
             \     : ''
             \ )
             \ .s:draw_motion(a:key)
             \ .s:draw_replace_char(a:key)
```

The purpose of this part is to assign the right value to the variable `keys`. It's supposed to contain the keys to type. They are written in the typeahead buffer at the end of the function, using `feedkeys()`.

---

Currently, it can be divided into 3 parts:

```
           (
             \   s:draw_is_changing_dir(a:key)
             \     ? s:draw_replace_char(s:draw_intersection(a:key))
             \     : ''
             \ )
```

Replace the current character with an intersection if the direction is changing, or do nothing.

```
             \ .s:draw_motion(a:key)
```

Move the cursor.

```
             \ .s:draw_replace_char(a:key)
```

Replace the character under the cursor.

---

The value of `a:key` contains the key that was typed. For example, if I hit `<Down>`, it should contain the string `'<Down>'`.

The function `s:draw_replace_char()` should return 2 keys to replace the character under the cursor. The first key is always `r`, the replace command. The second one should be the character to draw (`-`, `+`, `\`, `/`, ...).

The function `s:draw_is_changing_dir()` returns `0` or `1`. It returns `1` if the character to draw is not parallel to the one under the cursor.

Before moving the cursor, I test the output of this function to decide whether I should first replace the current character with an intersection or do nothing.

The function `s:draw_intersection()` returns the character standing for an intersection, `+` or `X`, depending on the key which was hit. For example, if I hit `<Down>`, the function should return the string `'+'`. And if I hit `<PageDown>`, it should return `'X'`.

The function `s:draw_motion()` returns the keys to move the cursor in a direction. For example, If I hit `<PageDown>`, it should return `"\<Right>\<Down>"`.

How can I rewrite the assignment of `keys` so that it handles the 2 conditions described earlier, regarding intersections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, that's too much code to read through. It looks complicated though.
Just check the character under the cursor and draw appropriately.

```
set ve=all

fun! Drawchar(dir)
    let c = {'h':'-', 'l':'-', 'j':'|', 'k':'|'}[a:dir]
    norm!yl
    if @" =~ '[-|+]' && @" != c
        let c = '+'
    endif
    exe 'norm!r' . c
endfun

fun! Draw(dir)
    call Drawchar(a:dir)
    exe 'norm!' . a:dir
    call Drawchar(a:dir)
endfun

nno <s-right> :call Draw('l')<cr>
nno <s-left> :call Draw('h')<cr>
nno <s-down> :call Draw('j')<cr>
nno <s-up> :call Draw('k')<cr>
```